CloudWatch Display single property of @message
My @message object in logs looks like this
I'm trying to display just the body property and nothing else in the @message object and export that as JSON.
I'm sure there has to be a simple way to do this but can't figure it out
[
  {
    "@message": {
      "body": {
        "server": "na",
        "moreProperties": "more"
      },
      "more": {
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "@message": {
      "body": {
        "server": "na",
        "moreProperties": "more"
      },
      "more": {
      }
    }
  }
]

Ideal Output
[
  {
    "@message": {
      "body": {
        "server": "na",
        "moreProperties": "more"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "@message": {
      "body": {
        "server": "na",
        "moreProperties": "more"
      }
    }
  }
]

Tried doing Parse, tried to filter just for body
Parse does not appear to work well when desired output is JSON
